# Где писать проверку в паттерне PageObject?

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования, selenium-webdriver, ui

Доброго времени суток.
Вопрос первый:
Подскажите пожалуйста где правильно писать проверку на нахождение на нужной странице и нужно ли вообще писать:

В методе класса:

```
public class mainPage {
private final WebDriver driver;
By mainPageLocator = By.id("topLoginLink");

public mainPage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
}
public loginPage verificationMainPage() {
    driver.findElement(mainPageLocator).click();
    return new loginPage(driver);
}}
```

В конструкторе класса:

```
public class mainPage {
    private final WebDriver driver;
    By mainPageLocator = By.id("topLoginLink");

public mainPage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
}

public mainPage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
    if (!"mainPage".equals(driver.getTitle())) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("This is not the mainPage");
    }
}
```

Или писать проверку непосредственно в тесте:

```
@Test
public void createNewAd() {
   // driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    mainPage mainPageOjb = new mainPage(driver);
    mainPageOjb.submitLogin();
    Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.id("typewaiting")).getText().contains("Главная страница"));
}
```

Вопрос второй:
Какая должны быть структура теста:

```
@Test
public void createNewAd() {
    //некий код полного тест кейса
}
```

или

```
@Test
public void mainPage() {
   //некий заходим на главную страницу, проверяем что зашли
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = "mainPage")
public void login() {
    //некий код с вводом логина и пароля, проверка перехода
}

@Test(dependsOnMethods = "login")
public void myAccount() {
    //некий код с вводом создание чего то и проверка создания
}
```

Вопрос третий:
Как часто нужно вызывать проверки в тесте, только в конце сценария тест кейса или и на промежуточных этапах?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добрый день!

1. Проверку не нужно делать. В предварительных настройках теста Вы должны свой `WebDriver` отправить на начальную страницу теста, а потом уже ваши классы сами будут обеспечивать возврат необходимой страницы. Так что мне кажется, что это лишнее.

   Также, кроме паттерна `PageObject` можете взглянуть на паттерн `PajeFactory`, который возвращает Вам проинициализированный `PageObject`. Это тоже является своего рода проверкой того, на какой странице мы находимся.
2. Желательно (но необязательно) структура теста должна быть иерархической. Рекомендую для ответа себе на этот вопрос прочитать статью [How To Structure Your Test Code](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/37-oop).
3. - `Assert` всегда нужно вызывать в самом тесте и желательно в конце;
   - `Assert` для одного теста всегда будет один, иначе если у вас встречается их несколько в тесте, то ваш тест нужно разделить на несколько тестов.
   - `Assert` нежелательно переносить внутрь классов, которые не помечены аннотацией `@Test` (в вышеназванной статье также можно найти, как и где применяется `assert`). Любой `Assert` не имеет смысла вне тестирующего метода. Но можно сделать так (это нежелательно. Я не проверял, сработает ли тест правильно но попробуйте):

     ```
     @Test
     public void createNewAd() {
        mainPage mainPageOjb = new mainPage(driver);
        mainPageOjb.submitLogin(); 
        assertMethod();
     }

     public void assertMethod() {
        Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.id("typewaiting")).getText().contains("Главная страница"));
     }
     ```

**UPD:** Все же в `junit` можно сделать несколько `assert` в одном тесте, но это считается `bad smell code`. Если у вас все же возникнет необходимость во множественных `assert` в одном тесте, то тогда нужно учитывать то, что метод (тест) будет выполняться до первого `failed assert`.

Comment: Большое спасибо за такой расширенный ответ!!!
Единственно немного не понял:Assert нежелательно переносить внутрь классов, которые не помечены аннотацией @Test (в вышеназванной статье также можно найти, как и где применяется assert).

Те. так делать нельзя??
    //@Test
    public void createNewAd() {
        Assert.assertTrue(/*проверка*/);
    }
    //@Test(dependsOnMethods = "createNewAd")
    public void deleteObl() {
        Assert.assertTrue(/*проверка*/));
    }

Comment: @Денис Я добавил ответ на этот вопрос в свой основной ответ. Можете взглянуть.

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь, разобрался!!!

Comment: @Денис Пожалуйста! :)